# How to display sub categories using Collapsing Categories plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wp-list-categories

My site is using the Collapsing Categories plugin (Robert Felty). As a sidebar widget, it is working the way we want it. But now I've written a page, and I'm inserting the php code in the page, and I don't know how to make it display the same Blog sub categories that it displays on any blog post page.

The sub-categories of the blog category are:
- from-the-experts
- grilling-lifestyle
- grilling-tips-and-techniques

But when I add the php code to the page (using the page editor), it outputs all the top level categories, instead:
►Blog (118)

►Lamb (1)

►News (1)

►Recipes (59)

►Uncategorized (4)

This is the php code, taken from the readme.txt page:

```
[php]
echo "<ul class='collapsCatList'>\n";
if (function_exists('collapsCat')) {
    collapsCat();
} else {
    wp_get_categories('your_options_here');
}
echo "</ul>\n";
[/php]
```

What I want to know is what I have to put in that code to display only the few sub categories I want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by plugin author [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-sub-categories-using-collapsing-categories-plugin?replies=3#post-8151907)

```
$my_options=array(
   'inExclude' => 'include',
   'inExcludeCats' => 'blog',
  'showTopLevel' => false
);
echo "<ul class='collapsCatList'>\n";
if (function_exists('collapsCat')) {
    collapsCat($my_options);
} else {
    wp_get_categories('your_options_here');
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```